# exception in Arches loading map location

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, gis

while we are trying to add a new location to the map in Arches(python/django based GIS web development framework) it gives us this exception

Please help to fix this issue.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCmDB.png)

Comment: You should give full details of your tables and how you use them in Django if you want a proper answer.

Comment: I installed the demo Arches website, from here http://arches-hip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/#installation
Then  I set up the map loading using "Bing Maps Key (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx)"
So   I wanna add a specific geo- location and load that map into Arches loading map.
Example:  California ,US  location like wise